# C++ socket not sending data if sleep not added

Tags: c++, sockets, c++11, sleep

I'm writing a client in C++ for my AI project that communicates with a server written in Java, to which I do not have access to the code. They use TCP sockets to communicate: the server sends me a message and the client performs an action accordingly, such as generating a move or updating the board or declaring victory, defeat and so on. Now I have noticed that sometimes the socket gets stuck and the server sends back a timeout message, even though the client has never generated a move and never entered in the "YOUR_MOVE" else if, which is weird, because it computes the move in no time (a handful of milliseconds) and if I add a 50 milliseconds sleep either before send or receive it works like a charm. I wonder what could possibly go wrong. That's the code:

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <cstring>      // Needed for memset
    #include <sys/socket.h> // Needed for the socket functions
    #include <netdb.h>      // Needed for the socket functions
    #include <unistd.h>
    #include <string>
    #include <boost/algorithm/string/predicate.hpp>
    #include <boost/lexical_cast.hpp>
    #include <chrono>
    #include "AI.cpp"
    #include <locale>
    #include <thread>

    using namespace::std;

    void error(const char *msg)
    {
         perror(msg);
        exit(0);
    }

    class Client{

    private:
        AI* ai;
    public:
        int socketfd;

    Client(const char* serverAddress, const char* port){
        int status;


        struct sockaddr_in serv_addr;
        struct hostent *server;



        portno = 8901;

        sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

        if (sockfd < 0)
            error("ERROR opening socket");
        server = gethostbyname("127.0.0.1");
        if (server == NULL) {
            fprintf(stderr,"ERROR, no such host\n");
            exit(0);
        }
        bzero((char *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));
        serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
        bcopy((char *)server->h_addr,
              (char *)&serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr,
              server->h_length);
        serv_addr.sin_port = htons(portno);
        if (connect(sockfd,(struct sockaddr *) &serv_addr,sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0)
            error("ERROR connecting");



        ai = new AI();
        (*ai).distance();
    }

    ~Client(){
        freeaddrinfo(host_info_list);
        close(socketfd);
        delete ai;
    }

    bool startsWith(char c1[], char c2[]){
        int i=0;
        while(c2[i] != 0){
            if(c1[i]==0)
                return false;
            if(c1[i] != c2[i])
                return false;
            i++;
        }

        return true;
    }

    void substr(char c[], int pos, char* s){
        int i;
        for(i=pos; c[i]!=0; i++){
            s[i-pos] = c[i];
        }
        s[i-pos] = 0;
    }

    void play(){

        bzero(buffer,256);
        n = read(sockfd,buffer,255);

        if(startsWith(buffer, (char*)"WELCOME"))
            printf(buffer);

        string colour;
        if(buffer[9]=='l')
            colour="black";
        else
            colour="white";

        char* msg = new char[256];

        while(true){
            bzero(buffer,256);
            n = read(sockfd,buffer,255);
            //printf(buffer);

            if(startsWith(buffer, (char*)"VALID_MOVE"))
                cout << "Valid move, please wait" << endl;
            else if(startsWith(buffer, (char*)"OPPONENT_MOVE")){

                substr(buffer, 14, msg);

                ai->updateBoard(msg);
                cout << "Opponent move: " << msg << endl;
            }
            else if(startsWith(buffer, (char*)"VICTORY")){
                cout << "You win" << endl;
                break;
            }
            else if(startsWith(buffer, (char*)"DEFEAT")){
                cout << "You lose" <<endl;
                break;
            }
            else if(startsWith(buffer, (char*)"TIE")){
                cout << "You tied" << endl;
                break;
            }
            else if(startsWith(buffer, (char*)"YOUR_TURN")){
                cout << "YOUR_TURN branch" << endl;
                string move = ai->generateNextMove(colour, 3);
                cout << "Your move is: " << move << endl;

                int i;
                for(i=0;i<8; i++){
                    msg[i] = move.at(i);
                }
                msg[i] = 0;

                sprintf(buffer, "MOVE %s\n", msg);

                std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(40));
                n = write(sockfd,buffer,strlen(buffer));

                ai->updateBoard(move);
            }
            else if(startsWith(buffer, (char*)"TIMEOUT")){
                cout << "Time out" << endl;
                break;
            }
            else if(startsWith(buffer, (char*)"MESSAGE")){
                substr(buffer, 8, msg);
                cout << msg << endl;
            }

        }
        close(sockfd);
    }
};

int main()
    {
        const char serverAddr[]="127.0.0.1";
        const char port[]="8901";
    Client * client = new Client(serverAddr, port);
    client->play();
        delete client;
    return 0;
    }
```

P.S. This is my first post, please show forgiveness if I have involuntarily forgotten to provide some other information. Thank you.

Comment: "never entered in the "YOUR_MOVE" else if" - do you mean YOUR_TURN? I suggest adding some more debbugging print statements (cout), especially immediately before and after the 'read', and add an additional 'else' clause (with debug output) so you can see if you're not handing something that you receive. If you still can't solve it, add the complete output of your program to the question. (Style note: parameters to `startsWith` method should be `const`, this would remove the need for casting the string literals to `(char *)`).

Comment: Where does `buffer` come from? (Also, you shouldn't say `#include "AI.cpp"`, you should say ` #include "AI.h"`; you have a member called "socketfd" but use "sockfd" most of the time (but not always); and you're over-using dynamic allocation.)

Comment: You don't need the struct keyword in `struct sockaddr_in serv_addr;`. I would use a non-0 exit value in your error function, to follow convention. Use a smart-pointer for your AI object, or better yet, just make it an `AI ai;` member. Your general string functions shouldn't be in client class. But them in common utility file or better yet, use the standard algorithms to do that job. `(char*)"WELCOME")` This cast tells you something is wrong. Your function parameters should be `const char[]`. Don't use `new char[256]`. Use `std::vector<char>` and `data` function to get a C-compatible pointer.

Comment: I did some clean-up here and there. Thank you for your advices, it's my first-ever C++ program, since I am used to Java and I have learned it in a couple of days. Still room for improvement, I guess :D

Answer (score 0):

For what I can see you are taking for granted that when you perform socket read with

```
n = read(sockfd,buffer,255);
```

You seem to be sure that you always receive an entire command, but think what happens if you receive only "YOUR TU" instead of "YOUR TURN" 
You always clean the buffer and the next loop you receive just "RN" so you never process the command and the server remains waiting for your move.

What you should do is clean the buffer ONLY when you have received a full meaningful command.

If you uncomment the:

```
 //printf(buffer);
```

You can check if my theory is correct.

Comment: better replace `printf(buffer)` with `printf("%s -- ", buffer)`

Comment: It works in localhost, so it always gets all of the string :\

Comment: It prints "YOUR_TURN", but it doesn't go in the related else if :\

Comment: if it prints YOUR_TURN but does not enter the corresponding "else if" then either the startswith is buggy or the YOUR_TURN string is somehow dirty, I suggest to put some printf in the startswith and maybe check the the length of the actual string read from the socket.